# A command without name, in Click

Tags: python, python-click

I want to have a command line tool with a usage like this:

```
$ program <arg>            does something, no command name required
$ program cut <arg>
$ program eat <arg>
```

The Click code would look like this:

```
@click.group()
def main() :
    pass

@main.command()
@click.argument('arg')
def noname(arg) :
    # does stuff

@main.command()
@click.argument('arg')
def cut(arg) :
    # cuts stuff

@main.command()
@click.argument('arg')
def eat(arg) :
    # eats stuff
```

My problem is that with this code, there is always a required command name, ie: I need to run `$ program noname arg`. But I want to be able to run `$ program arg`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your scheme has some challenges because of the ambiguity introduce with the *default* command.  Regardless, here is one way that can be achieved with `click`.  As shown in the test results, the generated help with be less than ideal, but likely OK.

#### Custom Class:

```
import click

class DefaultCommandGroup(click.Group):
    """allow a default command for a group"""

    def command(self, *args, **kwargs):
        default_command = kwargs.pop('default_command', False)
        if default_command and not args:
            kwargs['name'] = kwargs.get('name', '<>')
        decorator = super(
            DefaultCommandGroup, self).command(*args, **kwargs)

        if default_command:
            def new_decorator(f):
                cmd = decorator(f)
                self.default_command = cmd.name
                return cmd

            return new_decorator

        return decorator

    def resolve_command(self, ctx, args):
        try:
            # test if the command parses
            return super(
                DefaultCommandGroup, self).resolve_command(ctx, args)
        except click.UsageError:
            # command did not parse, assume it is the default command
            args.insert(0, self.default_command)
            return super(
                DefaultCommandGroup, self).resolve_command(ctx, args)
```

#### Using the Custom Class

To use the custom class, pass the `cls` parameter to the `click.group()` decorator.  Then pass `default_command=True` for the command which will be the default.

```
@click.group(cls=DefaultCommandGroup)
def a_group():
    """My Amazing Group"""

@a_group.command(default_command=True)
def a_command():
    """a command under the group"""
```

#### How does this work?

This works because `click` is a well designed OO framework.  The `@click.group()` decorator usually instantiates a `click.Group` object but allows this behavior to be over ridden with the `cls` parameter.  So it is a relatively easy matter to inherit from `click.Group` in our own class and over ride desired methods.

In this case we over ride `click.Group.command()` so that when a command is added we find the default command.  In addition we override `click.Group.resolve_command()` so that we can insert the default command name if the first resolution is unsuccessful.

#### Test Code:

```
@click.group(cls=DefaultCommandGroup)
def main():
    pass

@main.command(default_command=True)
@click.argument('arg')
def noname(arg):
    """ does stuff """
    click.echo('default: {}'.format(arg))

@main.command()
@click.argument('arg')
def cut(arg):
    """ cuts stuff """
    click.echo('cut: {}'.format(arg))

@main.command()
@click.argument('arg')
def eat(arg):
    """ eats stuff """
    click.echo('eat: {}'.format(arg))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    commands = (
        'an_arg',
        'cut cut_arg',
        'eat eat_arg',
        '--help',
        'cut --help',
        'eat --help',
        '',
    )

    import sys, time

    time.sleep(1)
    print('Click Version: {}'.format(click.__version__))
    print('Python Version: {}'.format(sys.version))
    for command in commands:
        try:
            time.sleep(0.1)
            print('-----------')
            print('> ' + command)
            time.sleep(0.1)
            main(command.split())

        except BaseException as exc:
            if str(exc) != '0' and \
                    not isinstance(exc,
                                   (click.ClickException, SystemExit)):
                raise
```

#### Results:

```
Click Version: 6.7
Python Version: 3.6.3 (v3.6.3:2c5fed8, Oct  3 2017, 18:11:49) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]
-----------
> an_arg
default: an_arg
-----------
> cut cut_arg
cut: cut_arg
-----------
> eat eat_arg
eat: eat_arg
-----------
> --help
Usage: test.py [OPTIONS] COMMAND [ARGS]...

Options:
  --help  Show this message and exit.

Commands:
  <>   does stuff
  cut  cuts stuff
  eat  eats stuff
-----------
> cut --help
Usage: test.py cut [OPTIONS] ARG

  cuts stuff

Options:
  --help  Show this message and exit.
-----------
> eat --help
Usage: test.py eat [OPTIONS] ARG

  eats stuff

Options:
  --help  Show this message and exit.
-----------
> 
Usage: test.py [OPTIONS] COMMAND [ARGS]...

Options:
  --help  Show this message and exit.

Commands:
  <>   does stuff
  cut  cuts stuff
  eat  eats stuff
```

Comment: impressive, but is it a bit of overkill? :)

Comment: @georgexsh, Thanks!  But as for the overkill question, this is but one custom class that is only 30 lines.  The OP was considering trying to do this with argparse.  Ouch.  If the overkill is really asking should anyone be able to do this?  No, not really.  The thing about truly great designs (like click) is, can the the disinterested user do the normal easily?  And can the interested user, change things with small amounts (of maybe non-trivial) code?  I think this answer demonstrates that a small of amount of, admittedly non-trivial, code can make significant changes to a brilliant framework.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I cannot implement it now but I'm super excited to try it when I get back home. This is indeed not something I could have done myself with my small knowledge of Python, but as you said Click seems to be a great tool because highly adaptable if you have some expertise.
That is, I have one question remaining : I don't see the call to `main()` after `if __name__ == "__main__":`. Why is that?

Comment: @8827, the call to `main` is in the `try` block.  That is so that I can re-call it for each test case.

Comment: @StephenRauch this is great - it seems to have killed the possibility to programmatically call a function decorated as a click command though, could it be possible ?

Comment: @Vincent, this should not significantly change how a called function behaves.  You might be interested in https://stackoverflow.com/a/48727139/7311767

Comment: Amazing thanks - didn't know about that approach, thought the process was easier.

Answer (score 11):

There is an option for you, ["Group Invocation Without Command
"](http://click.pocoo.org/5/commands/#group-invocation-without-command):

```
@click.group(invoke_without_command=True)
@click.pass_context
def main(ctx):
    if not ctx.invoked_subcommand:
        print('main stuff')
```

Comment: Thanks! I believe this is not optimal though because we need to run `$ program fooarg` or `$ program fooarg cut bararg$` instead of `$ program cut bararg$`. This code makes the argument for the `main()` function mandatory for any other command.

Comment: why you can’t make it optional?

Comment: The result if the same is I add a `required = False`.

Comment: I see that's not an easy task, it will be hard to determine `fooarg` is an argument for `main` but not a subcommand. maybe you could turn arguments into options.

Comment: I see. Well this wouldn't be very terminally. I think the less not elegant solution is to name the command… do you know if it is possible to resolve the problem with argparse?

Comment: I tried already with both argparse and Docopt. Docopt was ideal but I couldn't get around it because of the lack of documentation. Anyway thanks a lot for your effort!

Answer (score 9):

[click-default-group](https://github.com/click-contrib/click-default-group) is doing what  you are looking for. It is part of the click-contrib collection.

The advantage of that instead of using `invoke_without_command` is that it passes the options and arguments flawlessly to the default command, something that is not trivial (or even possible) with the built-in functionality.

Example code:

```py
import click
from click_default_group import DefaultGroup

@click.group(cls=DefaultGroup, default='foo', default_if_no_args=True)
def cli():
    print("group execution")

@cli.command()
@click.option('--config', default=None)
def foo(config):
    click.echo('foo execution')
    if config:
        click.echo(config)
```

Then, it's possible to call `foo` command with its option as:

```
$ program foo --config bar     <-- normal way to call foo
$ program --config bar         <-- foo is called and the option is forwarded. 
                                   Not possible with vanilla Click.
```

Comment: Thanks a lot it works great!

(I honnestly can't believe a cli tooling library wouldnt expose such an important feature)

Comment: `click_default_group` has not been updated in the last three years, is it still the best option?

Answer (score 2):

I'm late to the game, but here is a solution based on the answers above but changed to require what I believe is the least amount of additional code to still achieve the default command behavior.

With this method, you are able to specify the default command at the group declaration instead of the command declaration.

```
class DefaultCommandGroup(click.Group):

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.default_command = kwargs.pop('default_command', None)
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

def resolve_command(self, ctx, args):
    try:
        return super().resolve_command(ctx, args)
    except click.UsageError:
        args.insert(0, self.default_command)
        return super().resolve_command(ctx, args)
```

Using this class:

```
# note that the name of the default command is a str here
@click.group(cls=DefaultCommandGroup, default_command='command_one')
def a_group():
    pass
```

This has the benefit of letting you add command in the usual way.

```
a_group.add_command(command_one)
a_group.add_command(command_two)
a_group.add_command(command_three)
```

Answer (score 0):

An end-to-end practical example:

```
$ test_click add -a 1 -b 2
---
add: 3

------------------
$ test_click sub -a 5 -b 1
---
sub: 4

------------------

$ test_click
enter a operation (add or sub): add
enter a number 1: 1
enter a number 2: 2
---
add: 3

------------------

$ test_click
enter a operation (add or sub): sub
enter a number 1: 5
enter a number 2: 1
---
sub: 4
```

the code:

```py
import click


@click.group(invoke_without_command=True)
@click.pass_context
def mycommands(ctx):
    if ctx.invoked_subcommand is None:
        manual_mode()
        pass

def manual_mode():
    
    tipo = input('enter a operation (add or sub): ')
    arg1 = input('enter a number 1: ')
    arg2 = input('enter a number 2: ')
    if tipo == 'add':
        add_f(int(arg1), int(arg2))
    elif tipo == 'sub':
        sub_f(int(arg1), int(arg2))
    else:
        print('type not know')


def add_f(arg1,
          arg2):
    print('add:', arg1 + arg2)

def sub_f(arg1,
        arg2):
    
    print('sub:', arg1 - arg2)    


@click.option('-a', 'arg1',
              type=click.INT)
@click.option('-b', 'arg2',
              type=click.INT)
@mycommands.command()
def add(arg1, arg2):
    
    add_f(arg1, arg2)


@click.option('-a', 'arg1',
              type=click.INT)
@click.option('-b', 'arg2',
              type=click.INT)
@mycommands.command()
def sub(arg1,
        arg2):
    
    sub_f(arg1, arg2)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    mycommands()
```