# Combine cloup.group and click-default-group

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-click

I'm using cloup for my CLI for its constraints feature.

I have some commands a and b which have no common arguments.

```
import cloup


@cloup.group()
def cli():
    pass

@cli.command(show_constraints=True)
@cloup.option("--foo")
def a(**kwargs):
    print("hello")

@cli.command(show_constraints=True)
@cloup.option("--bar")
def b():
    pass

cli()
```

I want `a` to be the default command. So, I'd like the following output:

```
$ python3 main.py 
Usage: main.py [OPTIONS] COMMAND [ARGS]...

Options:
  --help  Show this message and exit.

Commands:
  a
  b
```

```
$ python3 main.py a --foo hey
hello
```

So far, this works as expected. Now I also want `a` to be the default command, thus I'd like to see:

```
$ python3 main.py --foo hey
hello
```

I know that I can have behaviour in `cli` as follows:

```
@cloup.group(invoke_without_command=True)
def cli():
    print("custom behaviour")
```

That will give

```
$ python3 main.py
custom behaviour
```

I thought that I could forward the call to `a` in the `cli` function, but the group `cli` does not know the option `--foo` of command `a`:

```
$ python3 main.py --foo hey
Usage: main.py [OPTIONS] COMMAND [ARGS]...
Try 'main.py --help' for help.

Error: No such option: --foo
```

I'm stuck here. I found an answer to the question here ([A command without name, in Click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52053491/a-command-without-name-in-click)), but I have to use `cloup.group`. So if I applied the solution there ...

```
@cloup.group(cls=DefaultGroup, default='a',default_if_no_args=True)
def cli():
    pass
```

... I'd get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 11, in <module>
    @cloup.option("--foo")
  File "<SNIP>/.venv_3.6.9/lib/python3.6/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1834, in decorator
    cmd = command(*args, **kwargs)(f)
  File "<SNIP>/.venv_3.6.9/lib/python3.6/site-packages/click/decorators.py", line 184, in decorator
    cmd = _make_command(f, name, attrs, cls)  # type: ignore
  File "<SNIP>/.venv_3.6.9/lib/python3.6/site-packages/click/decorators.py", line 152, in _make_command
    **attrs,
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'show_constraints'
```

And that's only the tip of the spear - any other features from `cloup.group` also become unavailable.

I guess one could merge the `group`s of `cloup` and `click-default-group`, but that looks horribly time-consuming. Is there an easier way to get a default command in cloup?

I also found https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/8.0.x/api/?highlight=group#click.Context.ignore_unknown_options. But if I understood correctly, only `command`s have a context and `group`s do not, so it wouldn't help.

Comment: Would passing a context to the group help? https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/8.0.x/api/#click.pass_context

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Author of Cloup here. You can try this:

```
"""
This example requires click-default-group.
"""
import cloup
from click import Context, HelpFormatter
from click_default_group import DefaultGroup


class GroupWithDefaultCommand(cloup.Group, DefaultGroup):
    # Optional: mark default command with "*"
    def format_subcommand_name(
        self, ctx: click.Context, name: str, cmd: click.Command
    ) -> str:
        if name == self.default_cmd_name:
            name = name + "*"
        return super().format_subcommand_name(ctx, name, cmd)


@cloup.group(cls=GroupWithDefaultCommand, default='alice')
def cli():
    pass


@cli.command()
@cloup.option("--foo")
def alice(**kwargs):
    print("Called alice with", kwargs)


@cli.command()
@cloup.option("--bar")
def bob(**kwargs):
    print("Called bob with", kwargs)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    cli()
```

AFAICS now, you'll only lose the "Did you mean" suggestion for mistyped commands (from Cloup) <strike>and the "*" indicating the dafault command (from click-default-group)</strike> (it was actually pretty easy to implement that with the method `Group.format_subcommand_name` introduced by Cloup). Let me know if you find any other problems. If it works well, I'll maybe add it to the examples folder.

Nonetheless, I'd suggest you to not use a default command at all. In click-default-group issue tracker, you can see it conflicts with click-help-colors and click-repl. So, unless you're not afraid of fixing issue that may potentially arise from having a default command, don't have one. As an alternative, you can just suggest your users to define an alias for the default command (e.g. by using the alias unix command).

Comment: Works like a charm! Interesting to see multiple inheritance actually working.
I can confirm what you observed concerning "Did you mean" and the "*". Apart from that, seems to be working fine!
I absolutely second your opinion on default commands, but due to legacy code, I have to roll with it. Thank you :)

Comment: I updated the code to re-introduce that "*" feature overriding a cloup.Group method.